# Sort one data set to get the best fit with another data set

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, matching

I'm currently working on an Excel program to manage employees at the checkout counters at a larger supermarket. It will load the employees' work schedules from an online database and then place the employees at the different counters.

Currently I'm at a point where I have loaded the schedules and divided the employees into the day shift and the evening shift in a sheet looking like this (only with much more people in reality):

```
   A     B    C      D     E    F
1  Name1 0745 1615   Name5 1515 2130
2  Name2 0830 1600   Name6 1600 2230
3  Name3 0915 1615   Name7 1630 2230
4  Name4 1000 1530
```

where `0745` is 7:45 and `1615` is 16:15 (4:15 PM)

Now, I would like to match a person from the day shift with a person from the evening shift so that ideally there will be a 15 minute overlap between all of them. As in the example above it is not necessarily given that there are equally as many people in the day and the evening shift, neither it will not necessarily be given that there can be an overlap of exactly 15 minutes between all teams of two. In this case, an overlap of 30 minutes is better than an overlap of 0 minutes for instance.

My own idea is to try all possible combinations of matches between the two data sets and then assign different error values to the different kinds of overlaps so for instance an overlap of 15 minutes yields a value of 0, 30 minutes yields 1, and 0 minutes yields 2, and then the best match is the one with the smallest total error.

However, I have no idea how to program this in VBA or if this is even the best approach.

I have tried searching the forum, but I didn't find anything helpful unfortunately. I hope one of you can help me or have an idea where I can search.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a lot of thinking behind the answer to your question. Writing the code for this is a bit of a project, in my opinion.

You could make your life a little easier by sorting columns A-C ascending by column C and sorting columns D-F ascending by column D.  If you're not working with a lot of employees, your answers will kind of fall out of that.  (In your sample data set, it becomes immediately clear that Name4 is paired with Name5 and Name1 or Name3 is paired with Name6.)

It's not a complete answer, but maybe it's a start.